# textconnection yielding additional space [R]

Tags: r, parsing

I have a string like the content of a csv file: `'"number 1", "number 2"'`, and I want to parse it.

I found `textconnection` can convert string into file handle. Parsing worked using it. But it generates some mysterious space in my content. Any one konw why and how to fix? Thanks

```
con = textConnection('"number 1", "number 2"')
dat = read.csv(con, header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
close(con)

dat
#         V1        V2
# 1 number 1  number 2

dat[1,1]
# [1] "number 1"

dat[1,2]
# [1] " number 2"   --- why there's a space???
```

Comment: This normal, because you have a space between after comma ( the separator is comma). You can remove it using `gsub("^ +","",dat$V2)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is already there, so it's not really a mystery.  Due to the way `read.csv()` parses the file, the space between the comma and the the quote is left behind.  You can resolve this by using `strip.white = TRUE` in your call to `read.csv()`.

```
con = textConnection('"number 1", "number 2"')
dat = read.csv(con, header = F, stringsAsFactors = F, strip.white = TRUE)
dat[1,2]
# [1] "number 2"
```

By the way, you don't need to use `textConnection()` in `read.csv()`. If you have a string, you can use the `text` argument of `read.csv()` to pass it in.

Comment: beautiful solution. Thank u so much! @Dirty Sock Sniffer. Clarify: strip.white = T doesn't remove spaces inside quotation marks